# angular.forEach loop with $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I want to create an array containing some objects

Firstly, I get a first array from the server containing a list of devices like this

```
 [ 
{accountID : "sysadmin",deviceID : "123"},
{accountID : "sysadmin",deviceID : "3"}
    ...
    ]
```

Then I create a second array containing some objects that each object represent a device(deviceID) and contains an array of events of this device that I get from the server

I do a loop upon the first array like this :

```
$scope.myArrayofDevices = [];

angular.forEach(response, function(device){ 

    $scope.myObject={};

    $scope.myObject.device = device.deviceID;

    $http.get('events')
        .success(function (data) {

        $scope.myObject.events = data;        

        });


        $scope.myArrayofDevices.push($scope.myObject);

    });//end for loop
```

I get events data from the server correctly .

But, when I check `$scope.myArrayofDevices` array I get an the first object with only the deviceID and no event array and the second object with deviceID and events array correctly

like this :

```
[
{deviceID : 123, events:},
{deviceID : 3 , events : array[5]}
]
```

How can I solve this issue ?

Note that I try to assign an array to `$scope.myObject.events` it works perfectly the problem is using a loop with $http

Comment: Try to define a new variable `myObject` inside the forEach callback function. use `var myObject = {}` instead of `$scope.myObject = {}`

Comment: thank you @Titus your idea solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `$q.all()` to resolve an array of promises and get the final result

```
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$q', function($scope, $q) {

    $scope.myArrayofDevices = [];

    $scope.getDeviceObject = function(deviceId) {
        return $http.get('events/' + deviceId).then(function(deviceEvents) {
            return {
                "device": deviceId,
                "events": deviceEvents
            };
        });
    }

    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(response, function(device) {
        promises.push($scope.getDeviceObject(device.deviceID));
    });

    /*
     * Combines multiple promises into a single promise
     * that will be resolved when all of the input promises are resolved
     */
    $q.all(promises).then(function(devices) {
        $scope.myArrayofDevices = $scope.myArrayofDevices.concat(devices);
    });


}]);
```

Comment: Deferred anti-pattern.

Comment: Answer edited to better match question.@dfsq you're probably right but I don't have a better answer at the moment and I think it's not that bad. I would love to read a better one ! ^^

Comment: Just remove $deferred, it's not needed. `$scope.getDeviceEvents = function(deviceId) { return $http.get('events/'+deviceId).then(function(response) { return response.data; }) }`

Comment: Simplified my code. I kept deferred but the promise now return the full device object because I'm not sure `/events` api returns the device ID. If this is the case then you're right, `deferred` can be removed ;)

Comment: Why downvote my answer ? Please provide arguments or a better answer...

Comment: The [`.success` method is deprecated and removed from AngularJS v1.6](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Comment: See my answer for a solution without the use of deferred (deprecated)

Comment: Probably downvote for abusing deferred (known as deferred anti-pattern). You should have just returned object from then block. Plus deviceevents in this case response object. Btw, answer from @Julien is also incorrect for that reason.

Comment: Ok guys, fixed !

Comment: Thank @Julien for the edit request, I forgot this deferred var ;) approved !

Comment: thank you @stej4n I'm getting a new error Cannot read property 'all' of undefined for using $q.all() . I inject $q in the controller like this :  
angular.module('myApp')
    .controller('DevicesCtr', [''$q',
        function ($q) {}]);

Comment: It should work, please post the full code of your controller so we can help

Comment: Answer completed

Answer (score 1):

First of all: like Carnaru Valentin said, you should create a service to wrap your `$http` calls.

Secondly, I don't get your `$http.get('events')` call. You don't pass any parameters to it (deviceID or whatnot).

Does it return a list of all events for every devices ? For a specific device ?

If you just forgot to add a parameter to the query: here is a solution that could work:

```
var promises = response.map(function (device) {
  return $http.get('events/' + device.deviceID)
    .then(function (data) {
      return {
        device: device.deviceID,
        events: data
      };
    });
})

$q.all(promises)
  .then(function (devices) {
    $scope.myArrayofDevices = $scope.myArrayofDevices.concat(devices);
    // alternatively: $scope.myArrayofDevices = devices;
  });
```

Comment: thank you for your help I get data perfectly from the server I put 'events' to simplify the code but my problem that in the final array some properties in objects inside the array are empty

Comment: You should try my or stej4n's solution !

`$q.all` will wait for all the promises to resolve and then return all the responses in an array.

Answer (score 0):

Thing is you reassign `$scope.myObject` to a new object before callback is fired and assigned events to the old one. So both callback's assign properties to same object.
You could just put all of the code in callback.

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Create a service:

    function DataService($http, appEndpoint){
        return {
            getLists: getData
        }

        function getData(){
            return $http.get(appEndpoint + 'lists')
        }
      }

2. Create controller:

function ListsController(DataService){
   var self = this;
   self.data = null;
   DataService.then(function(response){
       self.data = response.data;
   });

   // Here manipulate response -> self.data;
}
```