# How to extract multiple requests function to services/factory. angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, xmlhttprequest

I need to make multiple requests to the worldbank api. Ive searched for it and ive got some [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43410975/7376322) that helped me. But i need to extract it in a factory, and i dont know what to return on the controller.

**array**

```
        var indicatorsArray = [

        {indicatorId: "AG.LND.TOTL.K2", name: "Land Area, Total (km²)"},
        {indicatorId: "AG.LND.TOTL.UR.K2", name: "Land Area, Urban (km²)"},
        {indicatorId: "AG.LND.TOTL.RU.K2", name: "Land Area, Rural (km²)"},
        {indicatorId: "AG.LND.FRST.K2", name: "Land Area, Forest (km²)"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.POP.TOTL", name: "Population, Total"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.POP.GROW", name: "Population Growth"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.POP.TOTL.FE.ZS", name: "Population, Female (%)"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.POP.TOTL.MA.ZS", name: "Population, Male (%)"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.DYN.LE00.MA.IN", name: "Life Expectancy, Male (years)"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.DYN.LE00.FE.IN", name: "Life Expectancy, Female (years)"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.DYN.AMRT.MA", name: "Mortality, Male (1/1000)"},
        {indicatorId: "SP.DYN.AMRT.FE", name: "Mortality, Female (1/1000)"}


    ];
```

**factory.js**

```js
    function getIndicatorsData(country) {

        var getIndicators = function(indicatorId, name) {
            return $http.get("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/" + country + "/indicators/" + indicatorId + "?MRV=5&Gapfill=Y&format=json")
            .then(getIndicatorsComplete);

            function getIndicatorsComplete(response) {
                return {
                    "indicatorValue": response.data
                }
            };
        };

        var promises = [];

        angular.forEach(indicatorsArray, function(indicator) {
            promises.push(getIndicators(indicator.indicatorId));
        });

        $q.all(promises).then(function(indicators) {
            vm.bankData = vm.bankData.concat(indicators);
        });
    };
}
```

**controller.js**

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('country-detail')
        .controller('CountryDetailController', CountryDetailController)

    CountryDetailController.$inject = ['$location', '$window', '$http','$stateParams', 'countryDataService', 'worldBankService'];

    function CountryDetailController($location, $window, $http, $stateParams,countryDataService worldBankService) {
        /* jshint validthis:true */

        var vm = this;
        vm.country = [];
        vm.bankData = [];

        activate();

        function activate() {
            return getCountry().then(function(response) {
                vm.bankData = getIndicatorsData();

            });
        };

        function getCountry() {
            return countryDataService.getCountry(vm.countryCode)
                .then(function(data) {
                    vm.country = data;
                    return vm.country;
                });
       };



        function getIndicatorsData() {
            return worldBankService.getIndicatorsData(vm.countryCode)
                .then(function(data) {
                    vm.bankData = data;
                    return vm.bankData;
                });
        };
    }
})()
```

Ive tried to return the data on the controller, but some error comes up.

**I would like to know if there is some problems with my factory, and how to return the data on the controller.**

The best solution for me its to know how to extract [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43410975/7376322) in a factory.

Comment: how are you calling inside the controller?

Comment: i've updated the code including the controller file. please check it out

Comment: check my answer you have missed return statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not returning anything from factory

```
function getIndicatorsData(country) {
    var getIndicators = function (indicatorId, name) {
        return $http.get("https://api.worldbank.org/v2/countries/" + country + "/indicators/" + indicatorId + "?MRV=5&Gapfill=Y&format=json")
            .then(getIndicatorsComplete);

        function getIndicatorsComplete(response) {
            return {
                "indicatorValue": response.data
            }
        };
    };

    var promises = [];

    angular.forEach(indicatorsArray, function (indicator) {
        promises.push(getIndicators(indicator.indicatorId));
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

Inside controller

```
getIndicatorsData().then(function (indicators) {
    console.log(indicators);
});
```

Comment: man... love you! turns out that the problem was the absence of `return`. Thanks so much!